# Using find command to find files and archive them with date appended- Need a single find command

Tags: unix, find

I am trying to find files which are created/modified 30 days ago and will archive them. For this i am using Unix Find command. I am able to achieve the requirement with below command line.

```
 find . -type f -mtime +30  -exec basename {} \; | xargs -I file_name echo mv /home/Cyrup/chip/arc_poc/file_name /home/Cyrup/chip/arc_poc/arc/file_name_$(date +%Y%m%d) | ksh
```

However I would like to perform this task just using find command which i am not able to achieve. I tried to use below:

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv {} /home/Cyrup/chip/arc_poc/arc/{}_`date +%Y%m%d` \;
```

But its not working out. Here if {} acts as a place holder for all the files that are identified by find command. Then am i going wrong anywhere while moving files to archive Dir by renaming it with date?..

Also -mtime is for modified time of the file. Is there any way that we can find files based on creation time of the file. As per my knowledge we do not have any option with find command.

Thanks

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/create-achieve-with-all-files-from.html

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this just in the `find` command. You can maybe write a rename script  and use that in place of the `mv`:

```
find . -type f -mtime +30 -exec appenddate.sh {} \;
```

With appenddate.sh being something like:

```
mv $1 $1_`date +%Y%m%d`
```